# Receiving 'Cannot GET /' error on deployed Heroku page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I am building a MERN stack app. My Node server runs locally and connects to the MongoDB Database. It also builds and deploys on Heroku. But when I click Open App on the Heroku page, it says "Cannot GET /"

I resolved an earlier problem with Heroku by adding a script to install packages from various places. However, judging by the logs I'm not sure this problem has been fully addressed either. I know this new issue relates to routing but I'm not sure how to fix it. I have tried directing the express server to my React-router but it didn't resolve the problem. I have checked the Heroku logs but I'm not sure which part is causing the issue or how to fix it.

Heroku Logs

```
Mikes-MacBook-Pro-2:MealAppeal mikemooney$ heroku logs --tail
2019-04-28T20:21:16.311959+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-04-28T20:21:16.313440+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! MealAppeal@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "cd backend && node server.js" "cd client && npm start"`
2019-04-28T20:21:16.313707+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-04-28T20:21:16.314033+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-04-28T20:21:16.314251+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the MealAppeal@1.0.0 start script.
2019-04-28T20:21:16.314403+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-04-28T20:21:16.322349+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T20:21:16.322569+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-28T20:21:16.322706+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-28T20_21_16_315Z-debug.log
2019-04-28T20:21:16.418202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-28T20:21:16.437470+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-28T20:21:16.390801+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-28T20:21:19.158423+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-04-28T20:21:21.598120+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T20:21:21.598147+00:00 app[web.1]: > MealAppeal@1.0.0 start /app
2019-04-28T20:21:21.598149+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "cd backend && node server.js" "cd client && npm start"
2019-04-28T20:21:21.598151+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198219+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198242+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     throw err;
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198245+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     ^
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198247+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198249+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198250+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198253+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198255+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198256+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198258+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend/server.js:1:79)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198260+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198261+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198263+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198264+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.198266+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
2019-04-28T20:21:22.202647+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] cd backend && node server.js exited with code 1
2019-04-28T20:21:22.500772+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T20:21:22.500794+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > reactpractice@0.1.0 start /app/client
2019-04-28T20:21:22.500796+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > react-scripts start
2019-04-28T20:21:22.500798+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T20:21:22.508419+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
2019-04-28T20:21:22.514426+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! file sh
2019-04-28T20:21:22.514669+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-04-28T20:21:22.514672+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-04-28T20:21:22.514969+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-04-28T20:21:22.516571+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! reactpractice@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2019-04-28T20:21:22.516574+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-04-28T20:21:22.516869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-04-28T20:21:22.516871+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! Failed at the reactpractice@0.1.0 start script.
2019-04-28T20:21:22.517218+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-04-28T20:21:22.528693+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
2019-04-28T20:21:22.528696+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T20:21:22.528698+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-28T20:21:22.528700+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-28T20_21_22_518Z-debug.log
2019-04-28T20:21:22.530312+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] cd client && npm start exited with code 1
2019-04-28T20:21:22.539321+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-04-28T20:21:22.539812+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-04-28T20:21:22.540897+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! MealAppeal@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "cd backend && node server.js" "cd client && npm start"`
2019-04-28T20:21:22.541090+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-04-28T20:21:22.541366+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-04-28T20:21:22.541534+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the MealAppeal@1.0.0 start script.
2019-04-28T20:21:22.541699+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-04-28T20:21:22.547083+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T20:21:22.547289+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-28T20:21:22.547432+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-28T20_21_22_542Z-debug.log
2019-04-28T20:21:22.604833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-28T20:21:22.618061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-28T20:21:34.592020+00:00 heroku[run.2442]: State changed from starting to up
2019-04-28T20:21:34.503913+00:00 heroku[run.2442]: Awaiting client
2019-04-28T20:21:34.542485+00:00 heroku[run.2442]: Starting process with command `npm start npm start`
2019-04-28T20:21:30.534554+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `npm start npm start` by user mmooney363@gmail.com
2019-04-28T20:21:41.019594+00:00 heroku[run.2442]: State changed from up to complete
2019-04-28T20:21:41.001032+00:00 heroku[run.2442]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-28T20:24:45.343312+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=078058d4-18d6-44b0-ace6-6e53e4051b25 fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-04-28T20:24:45.900977+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=cd845788-1de1-4b2d-9ea7-7e450c652a00 fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-04-28T20:34:37.887950+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=2f48c1b3-c4c9-48ba-88c0-11d4e9bb8ba7 fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T20:35:37.799280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=bbe4aaf5-0489-429b-8a90-f13a383cbc0d fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-04-28T20:35:38.374255+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=7602f2b2-5c85-4ca3-8a93-bd39cb58bc6e fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-04-28T20:38:32.363448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=24d1fe95-dda4-4eb2-9d76-6588ad9efa8a fwd="107.77.204.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T20:44:55.678675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=f575eae8-48cc-452d-ba1a-7e56864923ea fwd="107.77.204.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T21:00:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mmooney363@gmail.com
2019-04-28T21:01:18.183801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=40e2548b-a329-4540-bbc3-f2910d0bf973 fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T21:02:15.004497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-28T21:02:14.815941+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user mmooney363@gmail.com
2019-04-28T21:02:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-04-28T21:02:14.815941+00:00 app[api]: Deploy e4d67b84 by user mmooney363@gmail.com
2019-04-28T21:02:29.397740+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-04-28T21:02:31.973090+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T21:02:31.973130+00:00 app[web.1]: > MealAppeal@1.0.0 start /app
2019-04-28T21:02:31.973133+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "cd backend && node server.js" "cd client && npm start"
2019-04-28T21:02:31.973135+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T21:02:33.086283+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T21:02:33.086325+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > reactpractice@0.1.0 start /app/client
2019-04-28T21:02:33.086327+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > react-scripts start
2019-04-28T21:02:33.086329+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T21:02:33.430175+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Server is running on Port: 52001
2019-04-28T21:02:33.489103+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] MongoDB database connection established successfully
2019-04-28T21:02:34.024406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-04-28T21:02:34.376137+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=dc9d434c-fbe7-49c4-bc4f-e5bd98fdb5cc fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=21ms status=404 bytes=415 protocol=https
2019-04-28T21:02:36.747810+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Something is already running on port 52001.
2019-04-28T21:02:36.788707+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] cd client && npm start exited with code 0
2019-04-28T21:03:37.537920+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=fb018ada-6847-47be-84f7-9707e4f5e4aa fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=415 protocol=https
2019-04-28T21:03:50.532398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/search" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=fe603c75-3a61-4d21-a483-25a67003f17d fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=421 protocol=https
2019-04-28T21:28:57.890665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=2644754d-418a-4c84-9b3a-b13e44805faf fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=415 protocol=http
2019-04-28T21:28:58.708960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=82dd5948-7516-4d52-875a-80f5f7394597 fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=426 protocol=http
```

Server.js:

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserRoutes = express.Router();
const models = require("./models");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use("/Users", UserRoutes);
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('./client/source/app.js'));
}

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

//Connect to Mongo
mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", function() {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || PORT, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});

//Routes
UserRoutes.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  models.User.find(function(err, Users) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json(Users);
    }
  });
});

UserRoutes.route("/:id").get(function(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id;
  models.User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    res.json(user);
  });
});

UserRoutes.route("/add").post(function(req, res) {
  let user = new models.User(req.body);
  user
    .save()
    .then(user => {
      res.status(200).json({ user: "user added successfully" });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("adding new user failed");
    });
});

UserRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function(req, res) {
  models.User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) res.status(404).send("data is not found");
    else user.user_name = req.body.user_name;
    user.user_password = req.body.user_password;

    user
      .save()
      .then(user => {
        res.json("User updated!");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
      });
  });
});
```

[image: File Structure]]

Answer (score 1):

The first error is because you are not requiring Express:

```
var express = require('express');
```

And to use Express Router, you'd want to declare the router, define the routes using it and then import the route file to use as middleware.

You could make a separate user routes file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
   //Route actions

});

...

module.exports = router;
```

And then import it and use it in your server.js file like so:

```
var userRoutes = require('./userRoutesPath')

app.use("/users", userRoutes);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I will implement those changes.